# How to get error details when OpenCV cv::imwrite() fails

Tags: c++, opencv, exception, error-handling

I'm using [`cv::imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce) to write an image to the disk in C++ using the OpenCV library. Unfortunately, the method only returns `bool` so I have been wondering how to get actual error details. The function can fail for a variety of reasons such as bad image, out of disk space or bad file path. Is there any way to get an accurate exception or error message? A certain Windows 11 user of my software is getting an image write failure (`cv::imwrite` returns `false`) while the same code works for many other users so I would like to get as much insight as possible into why that call fails to be able to mitigate the issue more easily.

- [`cv::redirectError`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga8cd28eccccb695570cdaf86a572d2c0c) callback is not called when `cv::imwrite` fails
- [`cv::strerror`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strerror.htm) does not exist

Comment: you can first "imencode" the image to a buffer. Then use your preferred error-aware method to dump the binary content to a file.

Comment: usual causes: directory doesn't exist, path contains non-ASCII symbols, permissions issue, input Mat is empty

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: It should be fine to use non-ASCII symbols, right? I just tried a file path with Chinese symbols in the file name and it worked correctly. However, both of you guys' comments helped me write a manual version of `imwrite` with better error checking.

Comment: * non-ASCII on windows. and instead of working around the problem (which is legitimate but...), I'd suggest browsing the opencv issues for a report (there must be dozens by now). someone suggested that fopen is to blame, which should be `_wfopen` instead on windows, or IDK what windows requires for this to not fail

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: I'm on Windows and a non-ASCII file path still worked. Maybe it was fixed in OpenCV4 or whatever. I use the latest available from vcpkg.

Comment: more likely it's a W10/W11 difference issue, or people have interesting locale/whatever settings. UTF-8 is this newfangled thing that microsoft only embraced recently

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by the comments, we can manually check for errors by using the `cv::imencode` function and verifying the file path for validity to provide better error feedback:

```
bool is_file_path_writable(const std::filesystem::path& file_path)
{
    const auto status = std::filesystem::status(file_path);
    const auto permissions = status.permissions();

    // Check if the file or directory is writable
    return (permissions & std::filesystem::perms::owner_write) != std::filesystem::perms::none ||
        (permissions & std::filesystem::perms::group_write) != std::filesystem::perms::none ||
        (permissions & std::filesystem::perms::others_write) != std::filesystem::perms::none;
}

void write_string_to_file(const std::filesystem::path& file_path, const std::string& file_contents)
{
    std::ofstream file_writer;
    file_writer.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    file_writer.open(file_path.wstring(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    file_writer << file_contents;
}

void error_aware_imwrite(const std::filesystem::path& output_file_path, const cv::Mat& mat)
{
    if (const auto parent_path = output_file_path.parent_path();
        !is_directory(parent_path))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Parent directory did not exist: " + parent_path.string());
    }

    if (is_regular_file(output_file_path) && !is_file_path_writable(output_file_path))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("File path is not writable");
    }

    const auto file_extension = output_file_path.extension().string();

    std::vector<uchar> buffer;
#define MB ((size_t)1024*1024)
    buffer.resize(10 * MB);

    if (const auto successfully_encoded = imencode(file_extension, mat, buffer);
        !successfully_encoded)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Imagine encoding failed");
    }

    // Write to the file
    const auto written_file_contents = std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
    if (written_file_contents.empty())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Written image bytes were empty");
    }

    write_string_to_file(output_file_path, written_file_contents);
}
```

Note that the `is_regular_file` check isn't strictly necessary but it makes the code "look" cleaner (e.g. if we don't check the file permissions of a non-existing file which actually will not throw an exception).